# Remove projects from solutions in Expression Blend 4?

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-4

Good evening,
I have a problem with my Expression Blend 4. I would like to remove a project from my solution but I do not know how to do this. I decided to simply remove the project's directory but now there is an unsupported project in my solution and Blend does not provide me any kind of remove button/link.
Is there any way to remove a project from a solution in Expression Blend 4 without creating a new solution?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you fixed it or not, but what i did, was the i edited it externally in Visual Studio, which i got installed - there's a link for edit externally in blend and then delete it with the remove button simply